# extracting filenames with a defined extension from a vector

Tags: r, vector, extract, filenames

How do you extract filenames with a defined extension from a vector ?

Example: If I have the vector:

> c("a.hdf", "b.tif", "c.jpg", "b.hdf", "t.tif", "z.png")

I want, for example, a vector with all the .hdf files. So the result would be:

> c("a.hdf", "b.hdf")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is your vector: `x[grepl(".hdf",x)]`.